# How to push the contents of the HTML while opening the side navigation bar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Here is the snap of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmazu.png)

On this image as I have provided after appearing of the side navigation bar the Hamburger icon and company images are hiding and how to close this side navigation bar using bootstrap, css.

Comment: This link here shows how to do a push navigation. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery to move the company logo and hamburger icon to the right upon the opening of the navigation and move back left upon closing of the navigation. If I'm reading correctly. It is a little hard to understand your question.

Just an example as I don't have actual code to reference.

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('collapsed'){
          //set position to relative if not set
          $('.logo').css({'position':'relative','left':'100px'});
          $(this).css({'position':'relative','left':'100px'});
     }else{
          //set back to 0 or original position 
          $('.logo').css({'left':'0px'});
          $(this).css({'left':'0px'});
     }
});
```